# can I temporarily disable an AirTag?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados, find-my, airtag

I have the following issue. I want my daughter to have an AirTag in her bag, but I want to disable it throughout the time she in school, as it interacts with her school iPad and makes her uncomfortable because the iPad tells her she is being tracked in front of her friends, for example.

Is there a way to predictably disable an AirTag for a specific set time (her school hours), and then re-activate it when she leaves school? Doing it manually is fine too, as long as it doesn't require physically tinkering wit the AirTag.

Answer (score 2):

Why not assign the AirTag to her Apple ID? Then it will trust the iPad and vice versa.

There’s no software disable feature so you would have to remove the battery when it can’t be “on” which is very much not practical from my point of view.

You could try [sharing the AirTag with her as that should suppress the tracking alert](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/share-airtag-item-find-iphone-iph419cc5f28/ios). This will not work if the account receiving the share is a [child account](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102617) so my first suggestion with the child account sharing to an adult might work. You can add six total accounts to a share (5 plus the “owner”).

A final “bad” suggestion is to put the iPad in airplane mode (no WiFi, no Bluetooth, no cellular) which also may be unworkable if the iPad needs to be operational and communicate to other devices just not an AirTag.

Comment: This would be a problem for several reasons. First, I can't share the AirTag on multiple phones or with multiple users because my phone is too old for that. So it has to be my apple id. Also, at school, she is not using her own apple id, but rather something provided by the school. Finally, I think it pops up on her friends iPads too, which I can't do anything about.

Comment: Well, you may be in a tough spot. Apple designed the tag to alert others that it is near. The sharing feature is new to me, but clearly isn’t intended for tracking an object carried by a child or a child currently.

Comment: There's probably something with family sharing for AirTags, isn't there? But that wouldn't solve the issue with the school-provided Apple ID.

Comment: @user2299502 regarding friends: AFAIK the message only pops up if it hasn't seen it's associated device for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the best method would be to block the AirTag signal during school hours.

No disassembly and battery removal required.

Just stick it in a faraday bag and take it out afterwards.

You can program the phone to send reminder message for that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_pWnIlxCic

or at [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=faraday%20cage%20bag&language=en_US&adgrpid=1232552894370279&hvadid=77034724558078&hvbmt=bp&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=79383&hvnetw=s&hvqmt=p&hvtargid=kwd-77034834622831%3Aloc-190&hydadcr=15623_13634045&tag=txtstdbgdt-20&ref=pd_sl_ff2t13tmg_p)

Comment: Great hardware solution. I’d love to see which bags can block the tag’s signal reliably and which do not.

Comment: And then the kid just doesn't take it out of the bag.

Comment: @MarcWilson that is what the phone call is for

Comment: @bmike great question. There are so many products on the market, and I am not equipped to test them

Comment: I remember a very well done test and can’t recall who did it - I’ll comment with a link in case you wish to incorporate.

Comment: if part of the purpose of the tag is to find the bag if it's lost, then it would be a shame if it were lost during school hours and was then unrecoverable

Comment: Is this to find the kid, or find some possession of the kid?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to silence AirTag tracking alerts, none of which will solve **all** the problems you mentioned:

1. Sharing the AirTag will cause it not to notify share recipients
2. Family members can permanently silence alerts (versus just for 24 hours)

Given your situation, you won't be able to accomplish what you're trying to do unless you block the signal (faraday cage, as mentioned) or remove the battery. Both of these are theoretically easy to do.